# How to resolve this equation to another value?

Tags: spherical-coordinates

Sorry guys, I don't know how to be more specific in the question without writing a way too long question...

Anyway my problem:

I have [this](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthodrome#Strecke) formula to calculate the distance between two points on the earth.
$$d=\operatorname{arcos}\left(\sin\theta_1\ \sin\theta_2+\cos\theta_1\ \cos\theta_2\ \cos(\phi_2-\phi_1)\right)$$

Now I need to calculate $\phi_2$.

I tried to change the formula myself but I failed to do it right. Now I am asking you guys to help me.
It would be nice if someone could show me how he resolves it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: please note that your question has probably already been answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369587/how-to-calculate-distance-on-a-sphere-with-an-earth-like-coordination-system).

Comment: @A.P. well as i see it he wants to know the distance between two points, my problem is i know the distance but i dont know how o get the value at the end of the given distance

Comment: I took the liberty of trying to improve the readability of your question using [Tex](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). I hope this is fine with you.

Answer (score 1):

This basically amounts to some algebraic manipulation.
You have a formula of the form
$$d=\operatorname{arcos}\left(\sin\theta_1\ \sin\theta_2+\cos\theta_1\ \cos\theta_2\ \cos(\phi_2-\phi_1)\right)$$
Now recall that $\operatorname{arcos}(x)$ is the inverse function of $\cos(\theta)$; therefore applying $\cos$ to both sides of the equation gives you the formula from the question I linked
$$\cos d=\sin\theta_1\ \sin\theta_2+\cos\theta_1\ \cos\theta_2\ \cos(\phi_2-\phi_1)$$
But you actually want to know $\phi_2$ so we start by taking $\cos(\phi_2-\phi_1)$ to one side of the equality and leaving the rest on the other side
$$\cos(\phi_2-\phi_1)=\frac{\cos d-\sin\theta_1\ \sin\theta_2}{\cos\theta_1\ \cos\theta_2}$$
Finally, we apply $\operatorname{arcos}$ to both sides of the equation and add $\phi_1$
$$
\begin{align}
\phi_2-\phi_1&=\operatorname{arcos}\left(\frac{\cos d-\sin\theta_1\ \sin\theta_2}{\cos\theta_1\ \cos\theta_2}\right)\\
\phi_2&=\operatorname{arcos}\left(\frac{\cos d-\sin\theta_1\ \sin\theta_2}{\cos\theta_1\ \cos\theta_2}\right)+\phi_1\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: It won't work like that when i try with my code. Does d need to be a radiant value too? Tried both but none gives me the right answer...

Comment: Everything should be in radians, yes. Could you please give me the example you tried? How did you check that it doesn't give you the right answer?

Comment: Found the mistake: you have to divide d with the radius of the earth before getting the cos(d): cos(d/6370)

Comment: Yes, @Andreas, that's exactly what it means for it to be in radians. ^_^